# MediaRecorder: stop called in an invalid state: 1

Tags: android

I am new in android. i create one Screen Recorder App. All things is done but problem is when i stop the screen recorder then it will not stop and this error occur.when is search on google about this error then i getting that MediaRecorder is not started but when i check on my sd card then captured video is saved.I follow this tutorial [here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/05/capture-record-android-screen-using-mediaprojection-apis/).
when i start the video recording then one notification is popup after click on then notification stop message then using service i try to stop mediaRecorder to stop but its not stopping and and error occur.If any one can help me then thanks in advance.

**Problem**
MediaRecorder.stop() not workging.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private ScreenRecorder mScreenRecorder;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mScreenRecorder = RecorderApplication.getApplication(this).getRecorder();
        shareScreen();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode != REQUEST_CODE) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unknown request code: " + requestCode);

            return;
        }
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Screen Cast Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        mScreenRecorder.initRecorder();
        mScreenRecorder.initShareScreen(resultCode, data);
        finish();
    }

    private void shareScreen() {
        if (mScreenRecorder.getMediaProjection() == null) {
            Log.i("getMediaProjection()..."," is null");
            startActivityForResult(mScreenRecorder.getMediaProjectionManager().createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        mScreenRecorder.initRecorder();
        mScreenRecorder.shareScreen();
        finish();
    }
}
```

**ScreenRecorder.java**

```
public class ScreenRecorder {

    private Context mContext;
    private WindowManager mWindowManager;

    private int mScreenDensity;
    private MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager;
    private MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
    private VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;
    private Surface surface;
    private MediaProjectionCallback mMediaProjectionCallback;
    public MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private String mTargetRecordFileName;
    private String mTargetRecordFilePath;

    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    public static final String NOTIFICATION_EXTRA = "Extra";
    public static final int EXTRA_PLAY = 0;
    public static final int EXTRA_PAUSE = 1;
    public static final int EXTRA_STOP = 2;
    public int flag = 0;

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    public ScreenRecorder(Context context, WindowManager windowManager) {
        mContext = context;
        mWindowManager = windowManager;

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        mScreenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    }

    public MediaProjection  getMediaProjection() {
        return mMediaProjection;
    }

    public MediaProjectionManager getMediaProjectionManager() {
        return mProjectionManager;
    }

    public void initShareScreen(int resultCode, Intent data) {
        mMediaProjectionCallback = new MediaProjectionCallback();
        mMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        mMediaProjection.registerCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback, null);

        shareScreen();
    }

    public void shareScreen() {
        mVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
        flag = 1;
        Log.i("shareScreen()...","mMediaRecorder.start()");
        Log.i("shareScreen()...",".."+flag);
//      showRunningNotification();
        showControlNotification();
    }

    private VirtualDisplay createVirtualDisplay() {
        int screen_width = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int screen_height = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        surface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
        return mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("MainActivity",
                screen_width, screen_height, mScreenDensity,
                DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
                mMediaRecorder.getSurface(), null, null);
    }

    public void initRecorder() {
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        int screen_width = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int screen_height = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;


        Log.i("initRecorder()...", " Initialization is Completed");

        try {

            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(screen_width, screen_height);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getSaveVideoFolder());
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);


            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            System.out.println("..........Media Recorder is Ready for Recording......");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getSaveVideoFolder() {
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/ScreenRecorder");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdirs();
        }
        mTargetRecordFileName = Utils.convertDateToString(new Date()) + ".mp4";
        mTargetRecordFilePath = folder.getAbsolutePath() + "/"
                + mTargetRecordFileName;
        return mTargetRecordFilePath;
    }

    private class MediaProjectionCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {

            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
            Log.v("ScreenRecorder...", "Recording Stopped");

            mMediaProjection = null;
            stopScreenSharing();
        }
    }

    private void stopScreenSharing() {
        if (mVirtualDisplay == null) {
            return;
        }
        mVirtualDisplay.release();
        // mMediaRecorder.release(); //If used: mMediaRecorder object cannot
        // be reused again
        destroyMediaProjection();
    }

    private void destroyMediaProjection() {

        Log.i("destroyMediaProjection()...","called");
        if (mMediaProjection != null) {
            mMediaProjection.unregisterCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback);
            mMediaProjection.stop();
//          mMediaProjection = null;
            Log.i("destroyMediaProjection()...","not null");
        }
    }

    private static int NOTIFICATION_RUNNING = 109;
    private static int NOTIFICATION_CONTROL = 110;
    private static int NOTIFICATION_DONE = 111;


    private void showControlNotification() {
        Intent intentPause = new Intent(mContext, FloatingViewService.class);
        intentPause.setAction("PAUSE");

        PendingIntent pIntentPause = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0,
                intentPause, 0);



        Intent intentStop = new Intent(mContext, FloatingViewService.class);
        intentStop.setAction("STOP");

        PendingIntent pIntentStop = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, intentStop, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                mContext);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
        mBuilder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Recording controls");
        mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
        mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
        mBuilder.setWhen(0);
        // if (!isPauseRecorder) {
        // mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_pause, "PAUSE",
        // pIntentPause);
        // } else {
        // mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_video, "RESUME",
        // pIntentPause);
        // }
        mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_stop, "STOP", pIntentStop);

        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_CONTROL, notification);
    }

    public void stopRecorder() {
        try {
            if (mMediaRecorder != null){

                Log.i("flag...","..."+flag);
                mMediaRecorder.stop();
                mMediaRecorder.reset();
//              mMediaProjection.stop();

                stopScreenSharing();

            }else{

                Log.i("mMediaRecorder...in stopRecorder()"," is null");
            }


        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error to stop media recorder in stopRecorder() method... :- "," "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_CONTROL);
        mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_RUNNING);

//      showDoneNotification();
        // TODO save info to database
        DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
        mDatabaseHelper.addVideo(mTargetRecordFilePath);

        // appendToFile(mTargetRecordFileName, getTemporaryFileName());
    }

    private String getTemporaryFileName() {
        return mContext.getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()
                + File.separator + "tmprecord.mp4";
    }

    private void appendToFile(@NonNull final String targetFileName,
                              @NonNull final String newFileName) {
        Mp4ParserWrapper.append(targetFileName, newFileName);
    }
}
```

**FloatingViewService.java**

```
public class FloatingViewService extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private View floatingView;
    private TextView mTextCoolDown;
    private WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
    private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsCoolDown;

    private ImageView btnCamera;
    private ImageView btnSettings;
    private ImageView btnAlbum;
    private ImageView btnExit;

    public static final String NOTIFICATION = "com.example.screenrecorder";

    private ScreenRecorder mScreenRecorder ;
    private ScreenRecorder mScreenRecorder1 ;
    private int cooldown = 3;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        windowManager = (WindowManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mScreenRecorder = new ScreenRecorder(getApplicationContext(), windowManager);

        if (intent != null) {

            if (intent.getAction() != null) {

                Log.i("intent Action...",intent.getAction());

                if (intent.getAction().equals("PAUSE")) {

                } else if (intent.getAction().equals("STOP")) {
                    mScreenRecorder.stopRecorder();
                    try{
                        showFloatingView();

                    }catch (RuntimeException e){

                    }
                } 
            }
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        initView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (floatingView != null)
            windowManager.removeView(floatingView);
    }

    private void initView() {
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        int screen_height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        floatingView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.floating_view, null);

        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        btnCamera = (ImageView) floatingView.findViewById(R.id.btn_camera);
        btnSettings = (ImageView) floatingView.findViewById(R.id.btn_settings);
        btnAlbum = (ImageView) floatingView.findViewById(R.id.btn_album);
        btnExit = (ImageView) floatingView.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);

        btnCamera.setOnTouchListener(new OnItemTouchListener(0));
        btnSettings.setOnTouchListener(new OnItemTouchListener(1));
        btnAlbum.setOnTouchListener(new OnItemTouchListener(2));

        btnExit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                stopSelf();

            }
        });

        setFloatingViewMove();

    }

    private void showFloatingView() {
        windowManager.addView(floatingView, params);
    }

    private void hideFloatingView() {
        windowManager.removeView(floatingView);
    }

    private int mAction = -1;
    long onTouchTime = -1;
    long TIME_CLICK = 200;

    private class OnItemTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

        private int action;

        public OnItemTouchListener(int action) {
            this.action = action;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mAction = action;
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_item_selected);
                onTouchTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void setFloatingViewMove() {
        floatingView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.d("phucdl", "start recorder " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - onTouchTime));

                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - onTouchTime < TIME_CLICK) {
                        Intent intent;

                        switch (mAction) {
                        case 0:
                            if (RecorderApplication.getApplication(FloatingViewService.this).getRecorder() == null) {
                                mScreenRecorder = new ScreenRecorder(FloatingViewService.this, windowManager);
                                RecorderApplication.getApplication(FloatingViewService.this).setRecorder(mScreenRecorder);
                            }
                            intent = new Intent(FloatingViewService.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            hideFloatingView();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            intent = new Intent(FloatingViewService.this, PreferencesActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            hideFloatingView();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            intent = new Intent(FloatingViewService.this, AlbumActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            hideFloatingView();
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    btnCamera.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                    btnSettings.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                    btnAlbum.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                    btnExit.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    params.x = initialX
                            + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY
                            + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(floatingView, params);
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Log** is

```
08-17 20:43:07.537 13733-13733/com.example.screenrecorder E/MediaRecorder: stop called in an invalid state: 1
08-17 20:43:07.537 13733-13733/com.example.screenrecorder E/Error to stop media recorder in stopRecorder() method... :-:  null
08-17 20:43:07.537 13733-13733/com.example.screenrecorder W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException
08-17 20:43:07.537 13733-13733/com.example.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
08-17 20:43:07.537 13733-13733/com.example.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at com.gameapp.screenrecorder.ScreenRecorder.stopRecorder(ScreenRecorder.java:371)
08-17 20:43:07.537 13733-13733/com.example.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at com.gameapp.screenrecorder.FloatingViewService.onStartCommand(FloatingViewService.java:59)
08-17 20:43:07.537 13733-13733/com.example.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3010)
08-17 20:43:07.537 13733-13733/com.example.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
08-17 20:43:07.537 13733-13733/com.example.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1442)
08-17 20:43:07.538 13733-13733/com.example.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-17 20:43:07.538 13733-13733/com.example.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
08-17 20:43:07.538 13733-13733/com.example.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
08-17 20:43:07.538 13733-13733/com.example.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-17 20:43:07.538 13733-13733/com.example.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
08-17 20:43:07.538 13733-13733/com.example.screenrecorder W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-17 20:43:07.732 13733-13750/com.example.screenrecorder W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-17 20:43:07.732 13733-13750/com.example.screenrecorder W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xed6bf5a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-17 20:43:09.433 13733-13750/com.example.screenrecorder E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xee9722a0
```

Comment: i think you are using notification to stop the mediarecoder...

Comment: yes sir, i stop media recorder using notification

Answer (score 2):

you create an Object of **ScreenRecorder** class First time in **FloatingViewService** class inside **setFloatingViewMove()** method that's ok but when you click on Stop then you again create **ScreenRecorder** class object then it's constructor is called and your previous MediaRacoder object is newly Initialized and then after you call stop method but mediarecoder start method is not called newly initialized mediarecorder instance that's why this exception is occurred.
 Just commant or remove one line in you **FloatingViewService** class in **onStartCommand()** method.I hope this will solve your problem.

```
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        windowManager = (WindowManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
       // mScreenRecorder = new ScreenRecorder(getApplicationContext(), windowManager);
}
```